# Mysql DB Design

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am designing a database with tables of customers and company_transaction where company is categorised in departments and each dept has its own daily customer domain.

For instance dept A deals with 100 customers in a day,and if there are 50 such dept., then the records will be 50*100=5000 per day and 35000 per week.

Now I am confused whether to put records of all dept under a single table, just like

**tbl_dept_transactions:**

```
---------- ------------- -----------
dept_id       cust_id     bill
----------  ------------ -----------
d1              c23        34780
d2              c34        45000
                .
                .
                .
```

or maintain a diff table for each dept..like managing transactions of one dept under its own table, just like,

**tbl_dept1_transactions:**

```
---------- ----------
cust_id      bill
---------- ----------
c45           56870
c56           56890
c34           32456
```

and also the dept keeps on adding and the data is adding at a higher rate as i told u, 35000+ records in a week and more if more dept would be added.

what would be the best option? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to set up a table for each department, as 1.8 million records a year could be alot for one table.

Comment: Could you tell us the defference between `company` and `customer` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would dynamically create a new table each month and suffix its name with the month.

Eg : `tbl_dept_transactions_2014_03`

Creating a table for each dept seems a false good idea, because sooner or later, it will be overloaded as well.

To maintain queries you can define a global constant with the current table name and use it in your queries eg : `define('TRANSACTIONS_TABLE','tbl_dep_transaction_'.date('Y_m'));`

About the tables created after 5 years, it's not very important if not for the data storage space, but if you'd like you can backup all tables for a given year, and delete them from the MySQL server.

Comment: If we create monthly one table, how many tables it will create in database for example 5 years, how to maintain query for the same.

Comment: Will creating a new table each month not overload the Database in long run? And how many no. of tables could be there in a mysql database?

Comment: It won't overload the database no. Actually I would directly create 10 years of tables from the start just so the system is in place (and put a reminder in 10 years :D) I don't think there is a limit for the number of tables in a database.

Comment: Although Creating tables on per month transactions basis seems a good idea. But Wouldn't it slow the website performance ?

Comment: If you prefer speed, then you could do one table per week, or even day, but it seems more complicated to use and maintain. At the end of the month, playing with 150k lines will be a bit tough for MySQL but still acceptable if you don't use too big queries. You can as well test it, populate a table with 150k rows, and try running the website with it.

Comment: what should be done to invoke the creation of table on the 1st of every month.

Comment: Creation of a script to create a table + creation of a crontab to call this script. This or checking if the table exist after defining its name in the code, and create it on the go if it doesn't exist (this is probably safer). Or creation of 100 years of table from the start.

Comment: I thought to use event scheduler inspite of crontab..Is my opinion viable?

Comment: and also can u suggest me a good example to learn the working of crontab according to my requirements ?

Comment: I don't know about event scheduler but the name sounds good.
First you'd have to build a php script to create a table in mysql. Then in a crontab, make a rule to call this script every month.
I'm sorry I'll be off for some time now, see you later.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have table `cust_id->bill` which will have partitions based on time and table `dept_id->cust_id`